# deleting the address item from a bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to delete the address from the inproceedings type of bibtex. I have learnt that I have to modify the .bst file. 
In order to do this, I have followed the idea of the answer from [bibliography style: merging the alpha style with the style of abbrv for author information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168936/bibliography-style-merging-the-alpha-style-with-the-style-of-abbrv-for-author-i)

In that case, I wanted to change the format of the citations.

No, I have tried to change the contents of the `inproceeding` entry of the `.bst` file, but I do not understand the syntax of this file.

Here, I put the code of the `inproceedings` entry in order to do more easier your future answers.

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      address empty$
    { organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
      organization output
      publisher output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { address output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
      new.sentence
      organization output
      publisher output
    }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: Please use `biblatex`, not BibTeX.  BibTeX is old, unsupported and creates more problems than it solves (as you've already noticed). Every time someone uses BibTeX, an innocent child learns to read from a book set in Comic Sans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the bit that reads

```
  address empty$
{ organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
  organization output
  publisher output
  format.date "year" output.check
}
{ address output.nonnull
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.sentence
  organization output
  publisher output
}
if$
```

This is a conditional block testing if the address is present. To remove the address from the printing, you need to force the route take. In an edited copy of the `.bst`, you can achieve that by replace all of the above lines with simply

```
  organization publisher new.sentence.checkb
  organization output
  publisher output
  format.date "year" output.check
```

This simply ignores the address entirely.